# Fade two images with different delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm trying to fade 2 different images on the same page with a different delay. The first image appears and then the second one appears.

Here's my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/4RvWY/3/

the css:

```
.panel img {
        opacity:0;
        -moz-transition: opacity 3000ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 3000ms ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 3000ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .shown img{
        opacity: 1;
    }

.img2{
    opacity:0;
        -moz-transition: opacity 10000ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 10000ms ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 10000ms ease-in-out;
}

.shown1 img2{
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

the html :

```
<div id="home" class="panel">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/3"/>
        &nbsp;
        <img class="img2" src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/1"/>

    </div>
```

my jquery attempt:

```
$('#wrap').find('.shown').removeClass('shown');
                $target.addClass('shown');
                $('#wrap').find('.shown1').removeClass('shown1');
                $target.addClass('shown1');
```

Comment: Bind to the transitionEnd events: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transition-callbacks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you may fix to get it working:

1) You're missing a dot (.) before the img2 in the `.shown1 img2` rule. You're referring to a class and not to an HTML tag. That must be like this:

```
.shown1 .img2{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

2) If you want to apply a delay to the CSS transition, you can specify it after the duration in the shorthand transition property, or in the transition-delay property. For example, for a 2s delay you can use:

```
.panel .img2{
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 10000ms 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 10000ms 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 10000ms 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/FL3RK/2/

Anyway, IMHO it would be nicer if you use the same duration (3000ms or 3s) for both transitions.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to wait for the animation to be completed to start it over again, put the transition property in your `.shown1 .img2` rule like this:

```
.shown1 .img2{
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3000ms 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3000ms 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 3000ms 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FL3RK/3/

Comment: Thank you pablopixel. It works nice, but if, I click on the next item Newsletter and then I come back to Home, the effect doesn't work.

Comment: OK, you didn't say anything about clicking ; )

Comment: yes pablopixel, you are right. I just remark it right now. It seems working when there is only one image byt with 2 not.

Comment: Anyway it's because you're using the same pic in "Newsletter". Click "Directions & Opening Hours" and come back to "Home" and you'll see it's working.

Comment: yes it works if I click on next button until Directions & Opening Hours and then previous to home. Which weird, it doesn't work if I click directly from the menu

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it's not about the images, it's because you have to let the fade-out transition finish before you start it over again. Otherwise it's starting at the point you left it. Click "Newsletter", wait 5s (2s delay + 3s transition) and come back to "Home", it's working.

Comment: Thx pablopixel, you were right, I had to wait 5s; It works nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var finished = 0;
var callback = function (){
  // Do whatever you want.
  finished++;
}
$(".div"+finished).animate(params, duration, null, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/2"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/1"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/2"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/people/4"/>
```

css

```
img {display:none;}
```

script

```
$("img").each(function(i) {
               $(this).fadeIn(2000*(i+1));
          });
```

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vishnurajv/px7U5/